# How to get columns/fields with peewee query?

Tags: python, orm, peewee

For a model

```
class User(db.Model, BaseUser):
    name = CharField()
    phone = CharField()
    age = IntegerField()
    points = IntegerField()
```

and a list of fields, `lst = ['phone', 'name', 'points']`

Is there a way to get your query to return the fields in `lst`?

I can't find an example in the [docs](https://ag-peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html), but it seems like Django's ORM has something like `...get().values(lst)`.

I tried passing the list as an argument to `User.select()`, but get

```
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

I guess I could do something like `[getattr(obj, field) for field in lst]` with a resulting object, but seems there should be a better way?

**Update**: The link to `values` in Django's docs is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values).

Answer (score 22):

You can use:

```
User.select(User.phone, User.name, User.points)
```

http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/api.html#SelectQuery

Comment: Thanks, I've been using that way (actually, something like `User.select(*[getattr(User, f) for f in lst])`) but was wondering if there's a way to directly pass a list of strings of field names like Django's `values` method. I'll update the question with a link to the docs I'm referring to.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
lst = [User.phone, User.name, User.points]

User.select(*lst)
```

I use this method to choose the fields dynamically `SELECT` from a predefined list.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this is to use `tuples` or `dicts`.

E.g for tuples from the docs:

```
stats = Stat.select(Stat.url, fn.Count(Stat.url)).group_by(Stat.url).tuples()

# iterate over a list of 2-tuples containing the url and count
for stat_url, stat_count in stats:
    print stat_url, stat_count
```

E.g for dicts from the docs:

```
stats = Stat.select(Stat.url, fn.Count(Stat.url).alias('ct')).group_by(Stat.url).dicts()

# iterate over a list of 2-tuples containing the url and count
for stat in stats:
    print stat['url'], stat['ct']
```

Remember that the results are iterators, so if you want the whole tuple or dict in memory you must initialize it with the defaults methods:
`tuple(stats)` or `dict(stats)`.

[More info here](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#retrieving-raw-tuples-dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your problem is, but did you try using [object_list](http://flask-peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#object_list), with using flask-peewee ?

```
def user_query():

   lst_result = User.select().where(User.name == lst.name)

   return object_list('yourtemplate.html', lst_result, 'list_user')
```

I am sorry if not much help.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like this is for Flask templates no? (which I don't use)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old one, but I found an answer recently.

Given an instance u from table User, then u._data returns a dictionary with field name as keys.

For example:

```
db.connect() # db was established with connection parameters for your database
u = User.get() # get one record
print u._data # get dictionary with field names as keys
db.close() # free up your connection
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of data is hidden in the metadata of the Model, you can access it like this:

```
User._meta.fields.keys()
```

This will return a dict_keys object if you want a list just parse it -> list()